# How to make sorting in DB by the number of items in the ListField?

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I have the next model:

```
class Departments(Document):
    _id = fields.ObjectIdField()
    name = fields.StringField(blank=True, null=True)
    department_id = fields.StringField(blank=True, null=True)  # Added
    list_of_users = fields.ListField(blank=True, null=True)
    list_of_workstations = fields.ListField(blank=True, null=True)
```

As you can see `list_of_users` and `list_of_workstations` are lists of items.

I wrote a code in Python, which takes all data from DB, put it into dict and then sorts as I need, but it works too slow.

How can I sort `Departments` right in the DB by the length of `list_of_users` or `list_of_workstations` or by ratio of `list_of_users/list_of_workstations`, something like:

```
departments = DepartmentStats.objects.order_by(len(list_of_users)).dsc
```

or

```
departments = DepartmentStats.objects.order_by(len(list_of_users)/len(list_of_workstations)).dsc
```

?

Comment: Read this documentation, probably you will find what you want.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone needs raw query:

```
departments = DepartmentStats._get_collection().aggregate([
    {"$project": {
        "department_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "list_of_users": 1,
    }},
    {"$sort": {"list_of_users": -1}},
])
```

and the case, when the result must be sorted by the ratio `list_of_users/list_of_workstations`

```
departments = DepartmentStats._get_collection().aggregate([
    {"$project": {
        "department_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "list_of_users": 1,
        "len_list_of_items": {"$divide": [{"$size": "$list_of_users"},
                                          {"$size": "$list_of_workstations"}]}
    }},
    {"$sort": {"len_list_of_items": -1}},
])
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first request, use annotation like Umut Gunebakan told you in his comment. But I'm know sure about Count() on ListField

```
departments = DepartmentStats.objects.all().annotate(num_list_users=Count('list_of_users')).order_by('-num_list_users')
```

For a desc order by, you just need to add the sign '-' (minus).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

The second request will be :

```
departments = DepartmentStats.objects.all().annotate(user_per_workstation=(Count('list_of_users')/Count('list_of_workstations')).order_by('-user_per_workstation')
```

**UPDATE: (Mongoengine used)**

With mongoengine you need to get item frequencies and sorted the result :
Check this part of [documentation - futher aggregation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#further-aggregation)

```
list_user_freqs = DepartmentStats.objects.item_frequencies('list_of_users', normalize=True)

from operator import itemgetter
list_user_freqs_sroted = sorted(list_user_freqs.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Mongoengine's QuerySets do not have such attribute as `annotate`

Comment: I edit my answer after some research in mongoengine documentation. Can you try it ?